# pip install in Dockerfile is failing

Tags: python, pandas, docker, pip, dockerfile

Hi I have created a Dockerfile for my app as below but it failed when I try to build the dockerimage .

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python ./index.py
```

here is the content of requirements.txt

```
flask
numpy
pandas 
SQLAlchemy
pyodbc
```

when it gets to RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
it can install flask but after that look like between numpy and pandas it start to generate error for many many pages.

any help?

Comment: add some of the error logs

Comment: what are the errors specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit your `dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc g++ python3-dev unixodbc-dev
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python ./index.py
```

edit your `requirements.txt`

```
flask 
SQLAlchemy
pyodbc
pandas
numpy
```

Comment: Thanks @Linpy 
I will go to test it , just a quick question: should I use pip or pip3 ? (my app is written in Python 3.7.4)

Comment: Just pip since you use python image

Comment: it works very well, thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please tell me, how did you find out what is the correct order of packages in the "Requirements.txt" file?"

Comment: I just find that by deploying in my env, so I am really do not have any explanation for it , maybe some dependencies are installed by Pandas that required in numpy